# pandas pivot table - rearrange

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with some columns. I want to rearrange them in a different way. An example is below:

```
time,name,feature,value
33 20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700,John,badL,2
45 19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700,John,badL,1
120 17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700,John,badL,1
220 20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700,John,totalL,20
450 19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700,John,totalL,15
330 18 May 2016 15:00:00 -0700,Mary,badL,2
330 18 May 2016 15:00:00 -0700,Mary,totalL,20
550 21 May 2016 12:00:00 -0700,Mary,adCmd,4
700 22 May 2016 16:00:00 -0700,Mary,PC,3
800 22 May 2016 16:00:00 -0700,Mary,eCon,200
```

Note: the first column value (time) is preceded by index values (33, 45,120,...).
From the above data frame, I want the resulting data frame as:

```
time,name,badL,totalL,adCmd,PC,eCon
20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700,John,2,20,0,0,0
19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700,John,1,15,0,0,0
17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700,John,1,0,0,0,0
18 May 2016 15:00:00 -0700,Mary,2,20,0,0,0
21 May 2016 12:00:00 -0700,Mary,0,0,4,0,0
22 May 2016 16:00:00 -0700,Mary,0,0,0,3,200
```

NOTE: for 17th may, John did not have any totalL. So, filled it with 0.

Is there an elegant way to do this? I am setting the time field as a pd.to_datetime, then, comparing...looks to be tedious. For the above example, I have only two 'features' (badL, totalL). I will have several more later.

This is what I have - but, it is adding a different row for the second feature...(totalL)....rather than putting it in the same row.

```
for f in ['badL', 'totalL']:
    dff = df[df.feature == f]
    print dff
    if len(dff.index) > 0:
        fullFeatureDf[f] = dff.feature_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `df.pivot`:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''
time,name,feature,value
33 20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700,John,badL,2
45 19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700,John,badL,1
120 17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700,John,badL,1
220 20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700,John,totalL,20
450 19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700,John,totalL,15
330 18 May 2016 15:00:00 -0700,Mary,badL,2
330 18 May 2016 15:00:00 -0700,Mary,totalL,20
550 21 May 2016 12:00:00 -0700,Mary,adCmd,4
700 22 May 2016 16:00:00 -0700,Mary,PC,3
800 22 May 2016 16:00:00 -0700,Mary,eCon,200
'''), sep=',').set_index(['time', 'name'])

df_new = df.pivot(columns='feature').fillna(0).astype(int)

#                                     value
# feature                                PC adCmd badL eCon totalL
# time                           name
# 120 17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700 John     0     0    1    0      0
# 220 20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700 John     0     0    0    0     20
# 33 20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700  John     0     0    2    0      0
# 330 18 May 2016 15:00:00 -0700 Mary     0     0    2    0     20
# 45 19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700  John     0     0    1    0      0
# 450 19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700 John     0     0    0    0     15
# 550 21 May 2016 12:00:00 -0700 Mary     0     4    0    0      0
# 700 22 May 2016 16:00:00 -0700 Mary     3     0    0    0      0
# 800 22 May 2016 16:00:00 -0700 Mary     0     0    0  200      0
```

Comment: Interesting. I did not know about this pivot function in data frames. Thanks for introducing me to this. As I said, I have a lot more features (f1, f2, f3..., f10). An example: for user John, I may have only 6 features, but, in the output data frame (df_new), I want all the 10 features as the columns and the appropriate columns populated with values and the rest with zeros. How do you do that?

Comment: Updated the question..with input and desired output.

Comment: I think pd.pivot_table(df, index = [list of features], fill_value = 0) might do the job....

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example with more features? Filling `nan`s can be done independently with `df.fillna(0)`.

Comment: I have updated with a better example with more features. Can you please help?

Comment: This works without major changes. I added `fillna` and conversion to int for a good measure, but the pivoting part is the same.

Comment: That works! The more I learn about Pandas, the more amazed I get. Much appreciated Yakym!

Answer (score 2):

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = '''time,name,f1,value
20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700,John,badL,2
19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700,John,badL,1
17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700,John,badL,1
20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700,John,totalL,20
19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700,John,totalL,15
17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700,John,totalL,12
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text))

print df

                         time  name      f1  value
0  20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700  John    badL      2
1  19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700  John    badL      1
2  17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700  John    badL      1
3  20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700  John  totalL     20
4  19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700  John  totalL     15
5  17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700  John  totalL     12
```

#### Solution using `unstack`

```
df = df.set_index(['time', 'name', 'f1'])

print df

                                        value
time                       name f1           
20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700 John badL        2
19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700 John badL        1
17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700 John badL        1
20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700 John totalL     20
19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700 John totalL     15
17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700 John totalL     12
```

then unstack to perform pivot.  It takes part of the row index and moves it to be columns.

```
print df.unstack()

                                value       
f1                               badL totalL
time                       name             
17 May 2016 11:00:00 -0700 John     1     12
19 May 2016 18:00:00 -0700 John     1     15
20 May 2016 14:00:00 -0700 John     2     20
```

---

In spirit, this is an identical solution to Yakym Pirozhenko.  Just a slightly different way of doing it.  This is more intuitive to me but may not be to you.

Comment: Updated the question..with input and desired output.